# Controlador no encuentra la configuracion de Twig en PHP

Tags: php, composer, twig

Tengo un problema a la hora de trabajar con twig en un proyecto con PHP.
Sin embargo, a la hora de llamarlo, me genera el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\BaseController' not found in C:\laragon\www\mecanicos\src\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php on line 6
```

Tengo 2 controladores, uno llamado `BaseController` donde defino la configuración para utilizar twig.
**BaseController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader;


class BaseController {
    protected $templateEngine;

    public function __construct(){
        $loader = new FilesystemLoader('../resources/views');
        $this->templateEngine = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
            'debug' => true,
            'cache' => false
        ]);
    }

    public function renderHTML($fileName, $data = []){
        return $this->templateEngine->render($fileName, $data);
    }
}
```

En donde deseo usarla es en otro controlador, llamado `HomeController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;


class HomeController extends BaseController{
    public function index(){
        
        echo $this->renderHTML('home.twig');
    }
}
```

y en mi archivo `composer.json` tengo declarado lo siguiente:

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
       "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"require-dev": {
  "phroute/phroute": "9999999-dev",
  "twig/twig": "9999999-dev"
}
```

Sin embargo, no logro hacerlo funcionar... ¿En que estoy fallando?

Comment: ¿Por qué esta es casi exactamente la misma pregunta que esta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906198/i-cant-connect-twig-with-php-controller/64907046) ? Además, su mensaje de error no coincide con el código que ha publicado.

Comment: El codigo de `HomeController` que muestras es el mismo que de `BaseController` puedes revisar si copiaste mal el codigo? de otra manera el archivo `HomeController` no concuerda en nombre con la clase que contiene

Comment: Porque el que posteo en el foro gringo fui yo. Normalmente escribo en ambos foros. Si esto no esta permitido, lo borro en alguno de los dos.

Comment: El nsmespace de basecontroller no es App\Http\Controllers, sino App\Controllers. En el homecontroller estás invocando el basecontroller desde un namespsce incorrecto.

Comment: Ya corregi ese error sin embargo me sigue generando el mismo error.